# What am I doing wrong with Bootstrap4?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am building an application page for an MVC site that I would like to be responsive on mobile devices.

The issue is that within a section I seem to be getting extra margins....

This is what I have currently have...

[image]

and it comes from the following HTML....

[image]

Those two inputs should line up on the same line and I am at about my wits end on why this is not functioning...

Thanks.

Comment: Those are default extra paddings/margins that come with the `form-group` and `col-x` classes. You might want to add utility classes like `p-0 m-0` to set the padding and margins to zero. Or `p-1` to set the padding to about 16px. Extra info --> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/#notation

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well.  While Galanthus's answer was what worked - I am happy to learn where that padding came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all after being using Bootstrap for many years since the beginning. You should never, ever put classes on the columns. This will mess up the Bootstrap grid CSS attributes and styling causing things like this to happen.

It is better to do the following:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
    </div>
</div>
```

Second, I have noticed that you are nesting columns without wrapping the nested columns inside another row.

Add a `<div class="row">` after the `col-md-10` and try again.

Comment: OMG Thank you that did it!   I am very new to front end layout as you can see.  Thank you also for the div form-group suggestion - I will be adding that as well.  Best practices are always welcome to me.

Comment: You are very welcome. And I am glad to help you out! bear in mind and never forget  to never add classes on the grid classes, cols, rows or container. Only after the container, row and inside classes.

Comment: That will be etched in stone in my memory of what not to do after I go and change the 30 or so other fields that are like that.....